# Select intervals from dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

How can I select a interval and store into a variable in dygraph javascript .

so suppose

I have this graph (This is done using dygraph library)

[image]

How can I store the value of the variable or atleast select the value

t1=22:10:38 and t2=22:10:41

and then store this interval into a variable like above .

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateWindow method to set/get the time intervals.
http://dygraphs.com/tests/dateWindow.html